# Why CLA = C0 class can no longer be used for their own use?

Tags: smartcard, javacard

I have a problem to find information about JavaCard3. I have to prepare a short persentation about new mechanisms in JavaCard version 3. I have a list of topics that must be touched during the presentation. One of them is **"why the CLA = C0 class can not be further used for own applications?**" Totally I can not find any information and references on the internet and JavaCard 3 documentation. Can any of you have such knowledge and tell why CLA = C0 can not be used for personal use anymore?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

APDU with CLA value of '0xC0' is addressed to the 4th logical channel. See chapter "Forwarding APDU Commands To a Logical Channel" in JCRESpec (page 4-9 in [version 3.0.1](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javame-419430.html#java_card_kit-3.0.1-rr-spec-oth-JPR)).

Excerpt (table 4-2):

```
CLA byte encoding         Semantic details
------------------------------------------------------------------------
%b1100 zzzz               (Type 16) last or only command in chain. no SM

NOTATION
z                         Logical channel indicator
                          Type 4 supports logical channels [0..3]
                          Type 16 supports logical channels [4..19]
```

EDIT> AFAIK, support for 20 logical channels started with JC 2.2.2

Comment: This seems to be correct, and utter stupidity at the same time, as this kind of class byte has been used to indicate a proprietary command with secure messaging in channel 0 before this was introduced. That's what happens if you start to grab *proprietary* commands and use them for your own purposes, in a generic framework.